# perl -pi -e remove .bak automatically on cygwin

Tags: bash, perl, cygwin

Under Cygwin, `perl -pi -e` will always save `.bak` files. I don't exactly understand why, but I want to get rid of it.

I usually use Perl pie like this:

```
git ls-files | egrep '[.](asm|c|h|inc)' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/'
```

Then I need to execute this:

```
git ls-files | egrep '[.](asm|c|h|inc)' | sed 's/$/.bak/' | rm -f
```

I tried to create a function but `xargs` doesn't like bash functions. Is there a way to easily combine my two commands together?

Of course I can rather use `find` or `ls` to get my files.

Actually the solution that might work the best for me is to declare an alias to `perl -pi -e` that automatically removes the unwanted `.bak` file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `perl -pi -e` does not create a `.bak` file, it alters the original file and deletes any temporary files. The `-i` switch actually takes an argument, and for you to get the backup you get you would need to enter `perl -pi.bak -e`. This could of course be some automagic feature of cygwin or your other software, but its not Perl. In Windows, you have to provide a backup extension to the `-i` switch, so perhaps Cygwin hacked one in there.

Comment: The `-i` command-line switch will create a backup file. It has an optional argument. Without an argument, it will use the extension `.bak`. To not create a backup file, don't use the switch: `perl -p -e` See `perldoc perlrun` and search for `/Command Switches/` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Comment: @shawnhcorey The documentation you link to does not describe the behavior you outline, and my experimentation and experience certainly don't support your claims, either. (I don't have Windows or Cygwin, though.)

Comment: @TLP Yes on Cygwin you have the same behavior as in Windows because the base filesystem is the same. However I don't know why this limitation exists on Windows.

Comment: @shawnhcorey I thought `-i` specify that the files are processed by the `<>` and edited-in-place. I don't know how to edit-in-place without `-i`

Comment: @coin Perhaps they just assume that Windows users need more hand-holding, or perhaps it just is some software limitation. You can however write a script to run in place, where you overtly open/alter/rename the file. You do not have to use the command line switches. For example: `... | xargs perl script.pl`. When they say "in-place edit", that's just another way of saying "open, read, print to new file, copy new file to old file", but it is done "under the hood", with a predefined functionality. Which in this case does not fit your requirement.

Comment: @coin If you can use `find` for this, you can write a full program in Perl to handle it all, using for example the `File::Find` module. I don't know how to translate your `git` command into a `find` command, but if you know the file structure, it would be a lot easier that way.

Comment: @TLP I initially wrote a script as you suggested, but I feel better to use native tools rather that multiplying the amount of required programs/scripts.

Comment: @coin Well, you would reduce the amount of required programs/scripts to just require Perl.... Not sure what you mean there. With my version below you don't even need Cygwin.

Comment: @TLP Indeed, but in my case I need Cygwin anyway.

Comment: @coin Well, you can use Cygwin if you want to. I'm just saying this solution has far fewer requirements, software-wise.

Comment: @TLP, Windows doesn't support anonymous files, which is why `-i` doesn't work on Windows. (`-i` opens the file, deletes it, creates a new file with the same name.) Cygwin is suppose to be a unix system, so `-i` is suppose to work, so it appears that `-i` was made equivalent to `-i.bak`.

Comment: @coin, Re "I don't know how to edit-in-place without `-i`", You can do the same thing `-i.bak` does: Rename the file, open the renamed file, create a new file with the original name. Read from the renamed file. Write to the new file. Just do the extra step of deleting the file afterwards.

Comment: @ikegami, On Cygwin, `perl -pe 's/// file' cat file on `STDOUT`. It doesn't edit-in-place. Moreover `echo "foo" > file && perl -pe 's/foo/bar/' file > file && cat file` gives nothing. Foo is empty. However I can do `echo "foo" > file && perl -pe 's/foo/bar/' file > file.bak && mv file.bak file && cat file`. This time it works

Comment: Re "On Cygwin,  `perl -pe 's///' file` outputs the file on STDOUT", Yeah, same with every other OS.

Comment: Re "Moreover `echo "foo" > file && perl -pe 's/foo/bar/' file > file && cat file` gives nothing", Because `>file` empties the file, there's nothing left for `perl -pe 's/foo/bar/' file` to read.

Comment: @ikegami Well, I didn't get your last point. It is not possible to edit-in-place without the `-i` or `-i.ext` option. I guess the best solution might be the Сухой27's one.

Comment: Re "It is not possible to edit in-place without the -i or -i.ext", Sure it is. Like you said, you got it to work. It's not truly in-place, but neither is `-i`.

Comment: As I mentioned, `-i.bak` does it this way: `mv file{,.bak} && perl -pe 's/foo/bar/' file.bak >file`. All you need to add is `rm file.bak`. But your way is safer (though `file.new` would make more sense than `file.bak`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use perl to delete `.bak` files,

```
.. | xargs perl -i.bak -pe 'BEGIN{ @d=@ARGV } s/foo/bar/; END{ unlink map "$_$^I", @d }'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run a Bash script in `xargs`.

```
git ls-files '*.asm' '*.[ch]' '*.inc' |
xargs bash -c 'perl -pi -e "s/foo/bar/" "$@"; for f; do rm -f "$f.bak"; done' _
```

Note also how I refactored out the `egrep` into `git ls-files`.

Answer (score 1):

On unix systems,

```
perl -i -pe'...' file
```

is basically the same as

```
exec 3<file
rm file
perl -pe'...' <&3 >file
```

`rm file` deletes the file name, but the file sticks around anonymously since there's an open handle to it. Windows doesn't support that, so Windows doesn't support `-i`.

It turns out that the code I posted **does** work on cygwin too!

```
$ echo foo >file

$ exec 3<file && rm file && perl -pe's/foo/bar/' <&3 >file

$ cat file
bar
```

For whatever reason, cygwin builds of Perl don't rely on that emulation of the unix feature and has `-i` behave as `-i.bak` (which does work on Windows).

If you really wanted to avoid temporary files, you could use the following:

```
perl -e'
   for $ARGV (@ARGV) {
      open(my $fh, "<", $ARGV)
         or warn("open $ARGV: $!"), next;

      unlink($ARGV)
         or warn("unlink $ARGV: $!"), next;

      open(STDOUT, ">", $ARGV)
         or warn("open $ARGV: $!"), next;

      while (<$fh>) {
         s/foo/bar/;
         print;
      }
   }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `find` to execute this command, you can use the Perl module [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) -- a core module in Perl 5 -- to replace the entire command with a Perl program.

Example of how to use this in a program file instead of a one-liner:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use autodie;      # file operation failures are fatal
use File::Copy;   # for move()

my $dir = shift;  # starting dir
my @files;
find(
    sub { 
        if (/\.(?:asm|c|h|inc)$/) { 
            push @files, $File::Find::name; 
        }
    }, $dir);

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, "<", $file;
    open my $tmp, ">", "$file.bak";
    while (<$fh>) {
        s/foo/bar/;
    } continue { print $tmp $_ }
    close $tmp;
    close $fh;
    move "$file.bak", $file;
}
```

You could possibly also pass the replacement as an argument instead of hard coding it, e.g.

```
my ($search, $replace, $dir) = @ARGV;
```

And then inside the loop use the variables:

```
s/$search/$replace/;
```

You would call it instead of your other command with pipes, something like this:

```
perl program.pl foo bar /some/dir
```

Comment: Do you really need to `close $tmp; close $fh`? You reuse the same fh at each iteration and your script is not doing anything else after that for loop

Comment: @coin Yes, I need to close both files in order to move them, otherwise the files will be busy and we get all sorts of nasty problems. Technically, there are ways around it, such as using a `continue` block, where the file handles would be auto-closed when they go out of scope. But why complicate things when this is so easy to do?

Comment: in your example `while (<>)` is supposed to iterate on `$fh` right? I thought `<>` applies only on `STDIN` and `ARGV`